# gtsummary get overall proportion instead of breaking down by category

Tags: r, gtsummary

sorry I'm new to R but I had to get a statistical summary. So i used gtsummary on a categorical varibale. The summary requires me to get the proportion of summary < 8 out of total number of records for both LMIC and Non-LMICS. Currently my code below gives me the breakdown of proportion for all numbers 3-13 as seen in the image. But i only want those < 8. How can I edit the code to get total gcs.1 sum/426 for LMICS and sum/377 for Non-LMICs and corresponding p-value.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irj90.png)

```
table1_gcs_prop %>%
  #filter(Total.GCS.1 < 8) %>%
  tbl_summary(
    by = Low.Middle.SDI,
    type = everything() ~ "categorical",
    statistic = list( all_categorical() ~ "{n} ({p}%)"),
    missing_text = "Missing"
  ) %>%  add_p()
```

Comment: You may have to `select()` the desired categories beforehand

Comment: @GuedesBF hi, thanks for your response. But when i did the filter before hand to get those < 8, my total N gets lesser. But i wanted the overall n to be the original number of rows. Also, the output is still separated by the categories

Comment: That is why I said SELECT, not FILTER

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.